# running same tests for different classes in groovy and spock

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, tdd, spock

I'm currently trying to run the same test cases for 2 different classes but having issues with the setup(), I see similar questions, but haven't seen the solution for groovy testing with Spock, and I haven't been able to figure it out.

So I am essentially solving the same problem using 2 different methods, so the same test cases should be applicable to both classes, I am trying to stay Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY).

So I've set up a MainTest as an abstract class and the MethodOneTest and MethodTwoTest as concrete classes that extend the abstract MainTest:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
abstract class MainTest extends Specification {
    private def controller

    def setup() {
        // controller = i_dont_know..
    }

    def "test canary"() {
        expect:
        true
    }

    // more tests
}
```

My concrete classes are something like this:

```
class MethodOneTest extends MainTest {
    def setup() {
        def controller = new MethodOneTest()
    }
}

class MethodTwoTest extends MainTest {
    def setup() {
        def controller = new MethoTwoTest()
    }
}
```

So does anyone know how I can do run all the tests in abstract MainTest from my concrete classes MethodOneTest and MethodTwoTest? How to instantiate the setup properly? I hope I am being clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just forget about controller setup. All tests from superclass will be automatically executed when you execute tests for concrete class. E.g.

```
import spock.lang.Specification
abstract class MainTest extends Specification {
    def "test canary"() {
        expect:
        true
    }

    // more tests
}

class MethodOneTest extends MainTest {

    // more tests
}

class MethodTwoTest extends MainTest {

    // more tests
}
```

But it should have sence to run the same tests more than once. So it is resonable to parameterize them with something, e.g. some class instance:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
abstract class MainSpecification extends Specification {
    @Shared 
    protected Controller controller

    def "test canary"() {
        expect:
        // do something with controller
    }

    // more tests
}

class MethodOneSpec extends MainSpecification {
    def setupSpec() {
        controller = //... first instance
    }

    // more tests
}

class MethodTwoSpec extends MainSpecification {
    def setupSpec() {
        controller = //... second instance
    }

    // more tests
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Worked perfectly for me. I'm testing a data structure library where I am doing several implementations of the similar structures, lists, stacks, queues, and this has saved me hundreds of lines of repeated code, because I can test all of there common properties through this method. Thanks a lot!